# Can I use my phone's internet to download files in a Win95 VM in Limbo emulator?

Tags: windows, proxy

I installed Limbo emulator from the Play Store, and found a Windows 95osr2 .img file on the internet. I want to install Opera instead of IE inside the VM, and use it to download some music.

I can't use dial up when I'm using it in an app, because it's too slow. It lets me connect via proxy server. I was wondering if I could use my phone with unlimited 4G LTE (Also is my hotspot one) to download the music off the archive site on mobile data for the proxy server.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Limbo supports this. Limbo's networking support uses user-mode support inside the guest operating system, and since Windows 95 is not an OS they have explicit support for, they won't provide drivers for it.

Instead, download the songs you want from your phone or another computer, and copy them into the .img before starting the VM.